# Image Normalization in Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have been working on finger image processing and I am currently want to do Normalization.

I have studied this link on [Griuale Biometric website](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/book/understanding-biometrics/types/enhancement/normalization).

The idea of normalization consist in changing the intensity of each pixel so that mean and variance of the whole image are changed to some predefined values.

Could any suggest me any example code or algorithm in java that can help me.

**EDIT:**

I am taking image pixel's `MEAN` and `VARIANCE` into account for the image normalization:

Here is my code:

```
public class NormalizeHistMeanVariance {
private static BufferedImage original, normalize;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final int N = 256; // Number of graylevels
    final int M = 250; // Max value in histogram for displaying purposes
    int nrows, ncols, size, in_img[][], out_img[][];
    int i, j, max, maxgray;
    double hist[] = new double[N], norm, mean, var, tmp;

    String f1 = "E:/single.jpg";
    String f2 = "E:/normImg";
    File original_f = new File(f1);
    original = ImageIO.read(original_f);

    Histogram histogram = new Histogram(original);
    in_img = histogram.getPixels(original);

    nrows = in_img.length;
    ncols = in_img[0].length;
    size = in_img.length * in_img[0].length;

    // Compute average gray and histogram
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        hist[i] = 0;
    mean = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
            hist[in_img[i][j]]++;
            mean += in_img[i][j];
        }
    }
    mean /= size;
    System.out.println("Mean graylevel = " + mean);

    // Compute variance
    var = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
            tmp = in_img[i][j] - mean;
            var += tmp * tmp;
        }
    }
    var = Math.sqrt(var / (size));
    System.out.println("Variance = " + var);

    max = maxgray = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (max < hist[i]) {
            max = (int) hist[i];
            maxgray = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Max count " + max + " (graylevel = " + maxgray
            + " )");

    // Normalize to M for better display effect
    norm = (double) M / maxgray;
    System.out.println("Norm = " + norm);

    out_img = new int[nrows][ncols];
    for (int x = 0; x < in_img.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < in_img[0].length; y++) {
            out_img[x][y] = (int) (in_img[x][y] * norm);
        }
    }
    normalize = ImageUtils.CreateImagefromIntArray(out_img);

    writeImage(f2);
}

private static void writeImage(String output) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(output + ".jpg");
    ImageIO.write(normalize, "jpg", file);
}
}
```

What i want is smooth image after normalization like in this [link](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/book/understanding-biometrics/types/enhancement/normalization). But I am not getting desired result. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You should have enough rep. to know that SO is not a code factory, and is not for vague questions.  -1

Comment: SO is not a human-powered google.com

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Code updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you dont need to use Histogram to perform this filter.

```
// Parameters to ImageNormalization
float mean = 160;
float variance = 150;

int width = fastBitmap.getWidth();
int height = fastBitmap.getHeight();

float globalMean = Mean(fastBitmap);
float globalVariance = Variance(fastBitmap, globalMean);

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

        int g = fastBitmap.getGray(i, j);
        float common = (float)Math.sqrt((variance * (float)Math.pow(g - globalMean, 2)) / globalVariance);
        int n = 0;
        if (g > globalMean){
            n = (int)(mean + common);
        }
        else{
            n = (int)(mean - common);
        }

        n = n > 255 ? 255 : n;
        n = n < 0 ? 0 : n;

        fastBitmap.setGray(i, j, n);
    }
}

private float Mean(FastBitmap fb){
    int height = fb.getHeight();
    int width = fb.getWidth();

    float mean = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            mean += fastBitmap.getGray(i, j);
        }
    }
    return mean / (width * height);
}

private float Variance(FastBitmap fb, float mean){
    int height = fb.getHeight();
    int width = fb.getWidth();

    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            sum += Math.pow(fastBitmap.getGray(i, j) - mean, 2);
        }
    }
    return sum / (float)((width * height) - 1);
}
```

Comment: If you need Mean and Variance in ImageStatistics tell me. :)

Comment: Have you calcuated the mean and vairiance like I did? If not could you help me what is your approach?

Comment: I saw your mean code. It is same as I did. Could you tell me how are you calculating the globalVariance?

Comment: It worked. Thanks a ton. You have made a superb library catalano framework. I will strongly recommend it to other people.

Comment: Hey is there any reason behind setting mean = 160 and variance = 150 ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I intend to make the project even bigger and better, and I'm studying to work in google glass too.

Comment: There isn't a reason, I just set this values, so you can modify.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37264/discussion-between-codefish-and-diego-catalano)